# htaccess authorization exclude URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cron

please, could you help me with my problem? I was looking for lots of exmaples (also this one: [htaccess exclude one url from Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978080/htaccess-exclude-one-url-from-basic-auth)) but I'm still not able to make it working :/
I have url `smth.com/databox_sync` and I want to exlude this url from htaccess verification. My htaccess looks like this:

```
    AuthUserFile /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/domains/akomin.cz/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My restricted Area"

        # set an environt

ment variable "noauth" if the request starts with "/callbacks/"
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^databox_sync noauth=1

    Order Deny,Allow
    Satisfy any
    Deny from all
    Require valid-user
    Allow from env=noauth

    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Symfony/web/$1 [L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm calling this adress via cron but cron returns:

> "Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required ...."

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SetEnvIf` line to this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(databox_sync|index\.php$) noauth=1
```

This is because you're routing everything to `index.php` in the last rule so `databox_sync` also gets routed to it.

Comment: It tried it, but doesn't work. Shouldn't I use %{REQUEST_URI} instead Requrest_URI ?

Comment: Still nothing :/ I think, server is just kidding.. :DD

Comment: Try to keep at first line. In other browser it also need authentification.

Comment: I have tested this exact code it worked for me without any auth dialog. Try first `SetEnvIf` line as: `SetEnvIf Request_URI databox_sync noauth=1`

Comment: Hm, still doesn't work :/ Shouldn't I change any server config?

Comment: Sorry I can't change anything in answer since exact same code worked for me on my Apache.