# htaccess exclude multiple url from Basic Auth

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

Hi i need to protect my app during the testing phase.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978080/htaccess-exclude-one-url-from-basic-auth) about excluding one url from Basic Auth

But i'd like to exclude 2 urls :

> /api/*
>
> /oauth/v2/token

So the entire app will be protected except for those two urls, that will be public. Otherwise i can't access my api routes.

My .htaccess for now is :

```
# Protect the app with password
AuthUserFile /home/master/public_html/web/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

So i'm guessing i should need some sort or regex in :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/api/ noauth=1
```

How can i have like a OR condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(api/|oauth/V2/token) noauth=1
```

You can exclude multiple URIs. Just seperate them using the pipe symbol `|`.

Answer (score 5):

Apache 2.4 Auth/Access control has changed since 2.2.
Here is the new syntax:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/master/public_html/web/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(api/|oauth/V2/token) noauth=1
<RequireAny>
  Require env noauth
  Require env REDIRECT_noauth
  Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap [`Require`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) inside another directive, like [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#directory) or [`Location`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#location)

```
<Location /api/>
Require all granted
</Location>

<Location /oauth/v2/token>
Require all granted
</Location>
```

---

Not asked, but [Getting it working](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking) says about .htpasswd

> This file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web. This is so that folks cannot download the password file.

So you shouldn't put .htpasswd inside `public_html`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i didn't know that! Normally on the web folder is accessible but i'll make sure.