# Restrict access to root folder htpasswd except api url

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I know that the question has been asked here : [htaccess exclude multiple url from Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642776/htaccess-exclude-multiple-url-from-basic-auth) but in the answer I didn't find the solution my problem so I reask here.

I want to block access to the root of a project in with htpasswd except for api url (it's not an existing folder but an endpoint controlled by index.php).

So far here is what I use for the htaccess :

```
<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth Required"
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(api|oauth)$" allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
</Location>
```

=> the htpasswd works but it blocks /api/xxx too.

Can somebody help me to correct that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/(api|oauth)(/.*)?$" allow

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth Required"
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=allow
```

[Also note that the `<Location>` directive is not allowed in `.htaccess`.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location)

Comment: Hi @anubhava, it still ask me for an authentification when I go for exemple in : /api/v3/docs => the Location directive is in the apache2 conf and not in a htaccess

Comment: I have tested this exact code in my root .htaccess and `/api/v3/docs` gets loaded without authentication. I suspect you have more rewrite rules somewhere that are rewriting `/api/v3/docs` type URIs to a front controller e.g. `index.php`

Comment: Indeed => do you know a way to handle that ? Thanks for your time

Comment: Try: `SetEnvIf Request_URI "/(index\.php|api|oauth)(/.*)?$" allow`