# Google Drive API - Not receiving push notifications (Basic Auth)

Tags: php, push-notification, google-drive-api, basic-authentication, endpoint

I am having problems with [Google Drive API - Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push). I did everything as specified in the documentation. Everything works perfectly to the step where I should receive "**sync**" notification to my endpoint.
I have secure endpoint (https), certificate by letsencrypt (certbot), I have registerd and verified my domain.
I suspect the problem is [**basic authentication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on my endpoint. When I created a channel I specified my endpoint like this:

https://username:password@mydomain.com/endpoint

Does this not work? Is there another way to specify that I have basic auth on my side?

**EDIT:**
I tested it without basic auth (I commented out basic auth in .htaccess file) and I received sync message. **So basic auth is the main problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like push notifications doesn't work with basic auth on endpoint, so I **excluded my endpoint URL from basic auth** by adding some rows to .htaccess file.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979889/5068563) for help.

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs about needing to authenticate in a specific way. How do you actually authenticate?

Comment: I was talking about push notifications authentication on endpoint side. More here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Thanks. Even though I had a slightly different issue, your response put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Silko's answer above put me on the right track.

The issue I had was that I had verified domain ownership under the wrong project in my Google console.

If you are authenticated sever-side using stored keys, make sure that your private key's project is the same as the one you've used in your console when verifying domain ownership. It wasn't at all obvious to me, either from the documentation or the console itself, that when you verify a domain, it's scoped to a single project rather than to a G Suite identity.

Hope this helps someone else.